# after I click on Calculate Button it goes to red screen

Tags: flutter

Hey guys I am learning Flutter by Angela Yu product , but my code wont work , can anyone help me with that ?
here is my Code

https://github.com/arvan903/bmi_calcuator_flutter

I think its because of my Flutter version

error :
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder(dirty):
The method '>=' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: >=(25)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder(dirty):
The method '>=' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: >=(25)

Comment: The two functions calculateBMI and getResult are called at the same time. Call the first function first then pass _bmi as an argument to the second function. In your approach, the _bmi variable will not update

Comment: Thanks Guys, I have found my problem